# How To Remove a Property From an IORegistryEntry (From User Space)

Tags: macos, keyboard, driver, mouse, iokit

I'm trying to remove a key-value-pair from the property table of an `IORegistryEntry`, but I just can't figure out how. I can use `IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty()` or `IORegistryEntrySetCFProperties()` to either **add** or **edit** key-value-pairs – but I cannot figure out a way to **remove** existing pairs.

---

**Background info**

The `IORegistryEntry` that I'm trying to edit has the class `AppleUserHIDEventDriver`. For every external keyboard or mouse you attach, an instance of `AppleUserHIDEventDriver` seems to appear in the registry. My macOS version is Ventura 13.3.1. I'm trying to do this from a program running in user space, not kernel space. If you need a minimal working example, let me know.

When I use `IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty()` or `IORegistryEntrySetCFProperties()` to set values on the `IORegistryEntry`, the values are actually not set in the top level of the property dictionary of the `IORegistryEntry` but instead they are set inside a subdictionary with the key `HIDEventServiceProperties`. I'm not sure why this happens, but it's exactly what I want in my case, so it's not a problem.

---

**Things I tried / thought about**

I tried extracting the whole dictionary using `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties()`, then remove the unwanted values and then write the whole dictionary back using `IORegistryEntrySetCFProperties()`. This works to change values, but the removed values are just ignored.

I managed to obtain a an HID Event Service Client reference instance (`IOHIDServiceClientRef`) to the same driver. It can also be used to **add** or **edit** key-value-pairs inside the `HIDEventServiceProperties` subdict. You can do this using the method `IOHIDServiceClientSetProperty()`. But I couldn't find a way to remove values using `IOHIDServiceClientRef`, so far, either.

I thought about using `IOConnect` (instead of `IORegistryEntry`) and it's dedicated methods for setting properties, but I don't think it would make a difference.

In the Apple docs there is [`IORegistryEntry::removeProperty()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/ioregistryentry/1811343-removeproperty) but it's a C++ method and can only be used from kernel space as far as I understand. So I haven't tried to use it, yet.

Maybe I could try to set the values on some other `IORegistryEntry` that is adjacent (a parent, child, grandchild, etc.) to the `AppleUserHIDEventDriver` instance which I've been working with so far. Not sure if that makes sense. I could also try to use (user space) `IOHIDDeviceRef` which is an interface to talk to one of those adjacent `IORegistryEntries` as far as I understand. `IOHIDDeviceRef` internally uses some COM interfaces like `IOHIDDeviceDeviceInterface` to commicate with the `IORegistryEntry`. Maybe those interface provide some methods to remove the properties.

---

**Update: Higher-level problem**

What I'm actually trying to do is to customize the pointer acceleration algorithm for external mice. Preferably without writing my own kernel level/DriverKit driver but instead by parametrizing Apple's driver from user space. The pointer acceleration algorithm is implemented inside the open-source `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp` (You can also find an implementation in `IOHIPointing.cpp` but I think it's deprecated and unused.) Apples code contains two separate mechanisms for specifying the mathematical curve mapping the physical speed of the mouse to the on-screen speed of the mouse pointer. The first mechanism is the **parametric curve** and the second mechanism is the **table-based curve**.

**Parametric curves** are basically simple 4th degree polynomial curves, while the **table-based curves** are basically specified through a number of points which are then connected with straight line segments to form a curve. (It's a bit more complicated in reality but that's irrelevant here). The **parametric curves** have the advantage of being completely smooth (they have a continuous derivative) and being - I believe – more efficient than the **table-based curves**. But the **table-based curves** offer much more freedom when it comes to the shape of the curve. Their derivatives are discontinuous but you can specify the curve with thousands of points making the derivative de-facto continuous and there is no discernible performance difference on CPU load (at least on my M1 MacBook).

So in order to freely customize the pointer acceleration curves I would like to first make the Apple Driver use the **table-based curves** (instead of the **parametric curves**) and then customize the points defining the **table-based curve** to my own liking.

The parameters for the **parametric curves** and the **table-based curves** can be found inside the `HIDEventServiceProperties` subdict contained inside the property dict of the `IORegistryEntry` of class `AppleUserHIDEventDriver` which (as mentioned above) shows up for every external mouse you connect.

You can find the params for the **parametric curve** under the key `HIDAccelCurves` (aka `kHIDAccelParametricCurvesKey`) and you can find the params for the **table-based curve** under `HIDPointerAccelerationTable` (aka `kIOHIDPointerAccelerationTableKey`).

In order to customize the acceleration curve of your mouse, you need to first change the curve-defining parameters mentioned above, then, for the changes to actually be loaded by the driver, you need to change another value. `kIOHIDPointerAccelerationTypeKey` has been working for me so far. As far as I understand it can be any of the "cachedProperties" defined in `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp` → `_cachedPropertyList`. When you look at `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp` → `setPropertyForClient` it seems that the acceleration algorithm is only re-initialized when one of those cached properties changes. (It is re-initialized by calling `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp` → `setupPointerAcceleration()`)

Now this was all working fine under macOS Monterey, but the big problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to activate the **table-based curves** under macOS Ventura.

That's because it seems that as soon as any value is present for the `HIDAccelCurves` key, the Apple driver attempts to use **parametric curves** instead of **table-based curves**. Pre-Ventura, the `HIDAccelCurves` key didn't seem to be present for third party mice by default, but under Ventura `HIDAccelCurves` is present by default.

> Sidenote: Strangely the `HIDAccelCurves` key doesn't seem to be present even under Ventura 13.3.1 when you start the computer without any mice attached, and only attach your mouse after the computer finished starting up. But if you start the computer with your mouse attached, then the `HIDAccelCurves` key seems to always be present, even after detaching and re-attaching the mouse – not sure what's going on here – haven't investigated too much. I think I also saw a discrepancy there after booting with a mouse attached, where the eventService (`IOHIDServiceClientRef`) seems to have the `HIDAccelCurves` key but the corresponding `IORegistryEntry`s `HIDEventServiceProperties` subdict didn't have the `HIDAccelCurves` key. Usually, these are always in sync. But I'm not sure if I really saw this, I might just have been confused or misremembering. I should test this more.

So that's my big problem: I'm trying to remove the `HIDAccelCurves` key from the `IORegistryEntry` of class `AppleUserHIDEventDriver` so that the code inside `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp` → `setupPointerAcceleration()` uses the **table-based curve** instead of the **parametric curve**.

But I just can't figure out how! I can set `HIDAccelCurves` to some bullshit, then the WindowServer crashes after I make the driver re-initialize the acceleration algorithm (as mentioned, I get it to re-initialize by modifying `kIOHIDPointerAccelerationTypeKey`), but I just can't completely remove the value for the key `HIDAccelCurves` once it has been set – which would be necessary for the driver to use the **table-based curves**.

> Sidenote: It feels like I could find some security exploit using this which would force Apple to improve the code so I can do my pointer acceleration. That would be such an absurd solution haha.

It might be worth investigating why `HIDAccelCurves` seems to be missing even under Ventura when you start without a mouse attached, but it doesn't seem like it would lead to a robust solution.

Another idea: `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp` also supports Microsoft COM interfaces. Specifically `IOHIDServiceFilterPlugInInterface` which is unfortunately private but shouldn't be hard to reverse-engineer. If we can get a reference to the instance implemented by `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter` we should be able to use the reverse engineered COM interface to set properties on it from user space. Could the `IORegistryEntry` of class `AppleUserHIDEventDriver` be the instance implementing `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter`? Not sure how this whole "filter" architecture works. Maybe we could try using `IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService()` on the `IORegistryEntry`, but I really don't know how all this COM interface stuff works and there aren't many examples on the internet, so I haven't tried, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General answer

So, the first thing you need to know about `IORegistryEntrySetCFProperties` is that the only thing you can know for certain is that it calls `setProperties` on the corresponding kernel object (`IORegistryEntry` subclass). By default, this [**does nothing at all**](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/5c2921b07a2480ab43ec66f5b9e41cb872bc554f/iokit/Kernel/IORegistryEntry.cpp#L575). (`IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty` in turn is [just a wrapper around `IORegistryEntrySetCFProperties`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOKitUser/blob/b0b3f822b7507c265aa8a1e37c3100c03ca82039/IOKitLib.c#L2635).)

**So, in the general case, you can neither set, update, nor remove properties on `IORegistryEntry` objects from user space.**

#### Attempt at an answer for your specific subclass

The above is of course technically a 100% correct answer, but not terribly helpful one. Clearly, your object has more than a no-op implementation of `setProperties`.

For setting or removing properties on objects of **specific** classes, we need to look at the behaviour of their overridden `setProperties` implementation.

The I/O Registry objects named `AppleUserHIDEventDriver` appear to actually be instances of the (kernel) class `AppleUserHIDEventService`:

```
$ ioreg -irn AppleUserHIDEventDriver
+-o AppleUserHIDEventDriver  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOHIDEventService:IOHIDEventDriver:AppleUserHIDEventService, id 0x100000c1f, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 12>
[…]
# see here: ->----------->------------>----------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Luckily, the source code for this class is open, and so we [can look at its `setProperties` implementation](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOHIDFamily/blob/1ca71a23b43de09cb3968515586840eacf817445/IOHIDFamily/AppleUserHIDEventService.cpp#L503). Unfortunately however, this class is just a kernel<->DriverKit glue class, so all it ultimately does is call

```
SetUserProperties(propDict, (uint64_t)&caller, _setPropertiesAction);
```

which in turn calls `SetProperties` in the DriverKit extension implementing the `IOUserClass`, which *is* `AppleUserHIDEventDriver`, and which does not appear to be open source, so we're at an impasse.

#### OK what next?

This seems a good opportunity to take a step back and think about the higher level problem you're ultimately trying to solve - right now, we can't see the forest for the trees. You haven't elaborated on your ultimate goal, but it greatly influences what steps are most sensible to take next. For example, if you're (working for) a device vendor, and you are trying to change the behaviour of your HID device on macOS, you may want to take a completely different approach and create a DriverKit Extension for your device, in effect replacing `AppleUserHIDEventDriver` entirely with your own logic.

Comment: Hi @pmdj, thanks for your very clear and insightful answer! I have added a section to my question about my higher level-goals. If you have any thoughts or advice I would be really grateful since I'm stuck at the moment! Thanks! :)

Comment: "which in turn calls SetProperties in the DriverKit extension implementing the IOUserClass, which is AppleUserHIDEventDriver, and which does not appear to be open source, so we're at an impasse." ––– I'm almost certain that `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter::setPropertyForClient()` is called at some point – which is open source. But I'm not sure how that happens or if it's helpful.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer, since it answers the original question, even though it doesn’t solve my specific problem. I would still greatly appreciate any tips on solving my specific problem.

Comment: @NoahNuebling Sorry, I’m really not an expert on such deep and subtle implementation details of the HID stack. I’d only be trawling through any public source code I could find to hunt around for ways to influence the logic, but that’d require quite a lot of time, more than I can realistically invest in a Stack Overflow question.